# Laragon define external Composer path

Tags: composer-php, laragon

I have just shifted from Wampserver to Laragon (portable). So far, everything is working fine.

However, I already have `Composer` installed in my system (so I removed it from the laragon/bin directory) and I am trying to point Laragon to it's location because Laragon can not install any framework as it fails to find the `Composer`.

I have already tried google this issue but could not find any relevant documentation or solution.

Comment: Please share more details - how you do use Composer? Is there any error message?

Comment: I am getting this error: `Could not open input file: <path>\Laragon\bin\composer/composer.phar`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question.